# What is the correct expression

Tags: expressions

I have been googling for a couple of time but could not get a satisfactory answer. Do we say :

*Defend a thesis in front of a jury*

or

*Defend a thesis before a jury*

Comment: Does [it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75859/need-to-know-the-correct-one-before-vs-in-front-of) solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine, but I'd prefer "in front of"

I don't think that "Jury" is the term used in the UK. A jury is the people who decide if you are guilty in a criminal trial.  "Jury" seems to be the word used in French.  I think if you want to use "jury" you should say "viva jury" or similar. Otherwise "examination panel" or similar is more common.

You can also say "Defend a thesis in a viva" or "viva voce".